# Error changing Virtual Environment to another version of python

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

I'm getting an error when I try to change which version of Python I use in the virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv -p /cygdrive/d/cygwin/lib/python3.2 test
Running virtualenv with interpreter /cygdrive/d/cygwin/lib/python3.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 783, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I'm able to create a new virtual environment if I leave the default version of python.
I only have virtual environment installed for python 2.7 and not 3.2. Do I have to install it for
python 3.2 as well? If so, how to I switch the default python cygwin uses to 3.2?
Sorry for the basic questions; I'm very new to using packages and cygwin.

thanks!
-Mark

These are my permissions settings

```
$ ls -la
total 25
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 Mark None    0 Sep 29 17:47 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 Mark None    0 Sep 29 16:50 ..
-rw-rw----  1 Mark None  380 Sep 29 17:47 .bash_history
-rwxrwxr-x  1 Mark None 1494 Sep 29 16:48 .bash_profile
-rwxrwxr-x  1 Mark None 6054 Sep 29 16:48 .bashrc
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 Mark None    0 Sep 29 17:20 .idlerc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 Mark None 1919 Sep 29 16:48 .inputrc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 Mark None 1236 Sep 29 16:48 .profile
-rw-rw----  1 Mark None    0 Sep 29 17:47 .Xauthority
```

Comment: What's are the permissions on your working directory when you type that command? (`ls -la` to see them)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
My brain is still in Windows file structure space. Cygwin wanted to see this:

```
$ virtualenv -p usr/bin/python3 test
```

and not

```
$ virtualenv -p /cygdrive/d/cygwin/lib/python3.2 test
```

Since I was pointing it someplace that it didn't have permission to access (let alone the version of Python I was looking for) it passed a permissions error. I think!

Thanks!
-Mark